# Remove whitespace from Python strings read from file?

Tags: python

I've been snooping around and people say to clear this issue you use `string.strip()` commands or similar to do this... However it isn't working for me... Please help?

I have:

```
file=open(~/Playlist.txt)
track=file.readline()
print track
```

And this gives the line from the file followed by a blank line of space which isn't even in the file... This wouldn't matter so much but and os.file.isfile(track) if statement after can't complete because of this... The strip command and iterations of don't clear this for me... What can I do?

Comment: you are reading just one line. Use this for line in file: print line.strip()

Comment: The fact that `strip` is a method, and not a command, suggest that you aren't using it correctly.  But since you couldn't be bothered to show how you tried, I guess we'll never know.

Comment: Please show your real code. Where did you learn to open and manipulate files like this in Python? Not in any tutorial I have read.

Comment: The "blank line of space" is because the character(s) indicating the end of the line are included in `track`, so that when you print it out, it skips to the next line; having nothing to print on that line, it appears blank.  All the more reason to use `strip` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Readline includes the trailing newline as well. I would recommend using string.replace("\n","") to replace all newlines in the line(ie the trailing newline that Readline leaves in). Another method is to use the string[:-1], but that would strip a character on the last line of the file, so it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

strip cuts newlines by default, so use

```
for line in file:
    print line.strip()
```